# Select multiple time slots on click

Tags: fullcalendar

When I click on a empty time slot on fullCalendar, it draws a rectangle on that empty cell. So, If my slotDuration is 30min, the block represents 30 min. I also can drag the cursor over multiple cells and select a custom range. But what I need to do is, when the user click (not drag) on a cell, select and draw the rectangle on 2 cells (representing 1 hour). Is this possible? I cannot change the slotDuration.
If I change the snapDuration to 1 hour, it works, but sadly, I cannot change it also.
What I was looking for is a way to override the `event.end` but that did not work.

**Update 1:**
I was able to do this exposing the `cellDuration` property:

on fullCalendar.js:

```
t.setCellDuration = function (minutes) {        
    var duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'minutes');
    var view = t.getView();     
    view.timeGrid.cellDuration = duration;
}
```

now on the `renderEvent` handler, I can call

```
element.fullCalendar("setCellDuration", 60);
```

It works but if there is an alternative that does not involve change fullCalendar code, it would be nice.

Comment: @downvoter: how can I improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do it just modifying the properties of the calendar, but you could do it modifying the fullCalendar.js file. Yes, I know you specify it on your question, but I think there is not alternative.

Exactly the `listenStop` function, which resides at line [4527 at version 2.3.3](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js#L4527)

listenStop check an array call `dates`

```
dates[
   {FCMoment}, //start
   {FCMoment}  //end
]
```

So, before that check, you can modify your end time as you prefer. In addition, you have to render it.
In your code, now listenStop() function should be something like:

```
 listenStop: function(ev) {
            if (dates) { // started and ended on a cell?
                if (dates[0].isSame(dates[1])) {
                    dates[1] = dates[0].clone().add(1, 'hours');    //Now we modify the end
                    _this.renderSelection(dates[0], dates[1]);      //And render the modified selection
                    view.trigger('dayClick', dayEl[0], start, ev);
                }
                if (isSelectable) {
                    // the selection will already have been rendered. just report it
                    view.reportSelection(start, end, ev);
                }
            }
        }
```